# При работе с fgets возникает ошибка сегментирования

Tags: c

Программа должна считывать из файла строку,находить запятые и записывать их адрес в масив, но на моменте считывания строки у меня возникает ошибка.

> Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск)

Точней она появляется при запуске программы. Компилятор не жалуется.
Почитав в интернете, я так и несмог исправить её.

P.S. Скорей всего не правильно искал.

```
#include <stdio.h> /*ввод и вывод*/
#include <string.h> /*строки*/
#include <locale.h> /*?????*/


FILE* open_file(char *f_ID,char *f_OD)  /*Проеряет на наличие файла и
                                    создаёт выходно файл*/
{
    FILE *StOD;
    FILE *StID;
    /*StreamID = fopen(fileID, "r"); */
    if((StID = fopen(f_ID, "r")) == NULL) {
        perror(" Заданый файл отсутствует:\n");
        return '\0';
        }
    else {
        StOD = fopen(f_OD, "w");
        fprintf(StOD, " Год, месяц, день, Время(ч.), Широта(гр.), Долгота(Гр.),Скорость(км/ч), Курсовой угол(гр.)\n");
        StID = fopen(f_ID, "r");
        return StID;
    }
}

char* search_comma_ad(char *OL) /*Адреса запятых*/
{
    char *ms[30];
    for(int i = 0, k = 0; OL[i] != '\n'; i++)
    {
        if((OL[i] == ',') || (OL[i] == ';')) {
            k++;
            *ms[k] = i;
            }
            return *ms;
}
}

int search_comma(char *OL)  /*Поиск кол-во запятых*/
{
    for(int i = 0, k = 0; OL[i] != '\n'; i++)
    {
        if((OL[i] == ',') || (OL[i] == ';')) {
            k++;
            }
           return k;
}
}

int main()
{

char *fileID;   /* Имя входного файла */
char *fileOD;   /* Имя выыходного файла */
FILE *StreamID; /* Указатель входного файла */
FILE *StreamOD; /* Указатель выходного файла */

char str[20];
char *locale, symbol, k, OneLine[100],  markers[30];
int i, max_i, NumberOfTracker, Hour, Minute, Second, Deg, Day, Month, Year;
float Time, Longitude, Latitude, Min, Velocity, Course, Altitude;

locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); /*Локаль??*/

fileID = "Витовт 449.txt";      /*Файл ввода*/
fileOD = "Витовт 449 вых.txt";  /*Файл вывода*/

StreamOD = open_file(fileID,fileOD); /*Создаёт заголовочные строки в вых файле*/

while(fgets(OneLine, 100, StreamID) != NULL)/*Считывает строку и сохран в масив*/
{
printf("Чтобы мои кривые указатели никого не смущали)");

  }
}
```

Comment: Что вы хотите сказать этим: `*markers = *search_comma_ad(OneLine);`? А заодно этим - `*ms[k] = i;`. У меня легкое ощущение, что вы как-то неверное представляете себе работу с массивами и указателями. Одного `*ms[k] = i;` в вашем коде достаточно для ваших неприятностей...

Comment: Ну ладно, добью, чтоб вам не мучиться... Итак, вы открываете файл `StreamOD`, а читаете из `StreamID`. Хватит? *P.S. Ну вот как люди учились программировать во времена DOS'а и Fido? Когда писать вопросы было практически некуда, и приходилось разбираться во всем самостоятельно? :)*

Comment: Фидо, Ноды.. телефон! :)

Comment: Только не бейте, ошибка остаётся. А я досихпор не понимаю, как исправить ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот наикратчайшая выжимка из Вашей программы:

```
int main() {
    char *ms[30];
    int k = 0;
    *ms[k] = 0;
    printf("Всё прошло удачно!\n");
```

Подумайте, почему после компиляции и запуска этой программы, мы видим вместо "Всё прошло удачно!" сообщение "Ошибка сегментирования" ?

Поясняю. Вы описали переменную *ms* как массив **указателей**. Хорошо... Далее Вы выполняете операцию *****, которая называется "взятие указателя" (разыменование). Т.е. программа должна взять **значение** адреса, которое которое хранится в переменной  *ms[0]*. Но какое значение там хранится?! Никакого. Ведь у Вас нигде нет оператора вида *ms[0] = что-то*;

Соответственно, программа не может записать значение по незаданному адресу. Это и есть ошибка сегментирования.